# Django Middleware does not modify request in tests

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-testing, django-tests

I am trying to create test class for my custom middleware. The project is using Django REST framework. Middleware class works fine when server is running, but when I run test it behaves not quite as I would expect it to do. Maybe I misunderstood something, as I am quite new to testing in Django.

my_middleware.py:

```
class FX:
    a = False
    b = None
    c = ''

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass

    def __str__(self):
        return 'fx ok'

class MyMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        request.fx = FX()
        response = self.get_response(request)
        print('done')
        return response
```

views.py:

```
class TestView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        print('View ok')
        print('FX: ', request.fx)
        return Response({'result':'ok'})
```

tests.py:

```
class TestMyMiddleware(APITestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        pass

    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def test_fx(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('TestView'), content_type="application/json")
        request = response.request
        self.assertTrue(hasattr(request, 'fx'))
```

The code above actually runs the middleware. It prints "done" form the middleware call, then prints 'View ok' and also prints FX instance. However request.fx is not available in the test_fx method, thus giving assertion failure:

```
self.assertTrue(hasattr(request, 'fx'))
AssertionError: False is not true
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Do you use a different `settings.py` for your tests?

Comment: No. Settings are the same for testing and running server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the request object from the response with `response.wsgi_request` instead of `response.request`.

```
class TestMyMiddleware(APITestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        pass

    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def test_fx(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('TestView'), content_type="application/json")
        request = response.wsgi_request
        self.assertTrue(hasattr(request, 'fx'))
```

Comment: Well... this worked like a charm. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and didn't find the other answer helpful. [Here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#checking-the-response-data) is the section in the docs that summarizes it.

To elaborate, there are two ways of reading data from the `response`,

1. [`response.data`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses/#data) and
2. [`response.content`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses/#content).

The former will show you the data that the view returned (before applying middleware and before being serialized into an `HttpResponse`). The latter will show you the underlying content of the `HttpResponse` object (after middleware but as a bytestream). Hence the documentation uses `json.loads(response.content)` inside the `assert*`.

Alternatively, instead of using `json.loads(response.content)`, it seems like you can also use [`response.json()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Response.json), which roughly makes sense since DRF's `APIClient` subclasses django's test `Client` class.

To reiterate, the reason `.data` and `.content` might defer is if you have some middleware manipulating the data after the view has returned the object but before the data has been serialized into an `HttpResponse`.

In my case, I was using `djangorestframework-camel-case` which was changing the names of the fields. I wasn't able to see the correct field names in `response.data`, but I was able to see it in `response.json()`.